# LinkedList(l) -> For l = [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and k = 3, the output should be solution(l, k) = [1, 2, 4, 5]

Tags: python, linked-list

## 9/10 test cases are passing, where is the leak?

Given a singly linked list of integers l and an integer k, remove all elements from list l that have a value equal to k.

```
def solution(l, k):
    len = 0
    
    l2 = l1 = ListNode(None)
    l1.next = l
    
    while l is not None:
        len = len + 1 
        l = l.next
        
    if len == 0:
        return l
    elif len == 1:
        if l1.next == k:
            return l
        else:
            return l1.next
    else:
        while l1.next is not None:
            if l1.next.value == k:
                l1.next = l1.next.next
            else:
                l1 = l1.next
    
    return l2.next
```

Comment: is k `ListNode` or int? if `k` is int then this condn is wrong `if l1.next == k`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: k is int. and l is listNode

Comment: I have modified if l1.next == k to if l1.next.value == k , thanks... It was the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have these lines in your code:

```
    if l1.next == k:
```

...and:

```
        if l1.next.value == k:
```

One of those two must be wrong, as the first compares a ListNode, while the other compares a ListNode *value*. Assuming that `k` represents a *value*, the first should be corrected to:

```
    if l1.next.value == k:
```

### Other remarks

- It is not necessary to first count the number of nodes in the list.
- It is not necessary to deal separately with the cases where the list has no nodes, or just one node.

Here is how your code could be reduced:

```py
def solution(l, k):
    prehead = ListNode(None)
    prehead.next = l
    l = prehead
    
    while l.next is not None:
        if l.next.value == k:
            l.next = l.next.next
        else:
            l = l.next

    return prehead.next
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, [if l.next == k]  should have been [if l.next.value == k]